How to determine the actual memory address of an ELF section given its virtual address?
A section in an ELF executable file has a virtual address where it will be loaded when the program is executed.
Similarly, loadable segments also have their vaddr and a segment will comprise of one or more sections.
But these addresses appear to be relative to a base address as the ELF spec mentions (refer the attached screenshot)
Based on this information, I've the following question:
I have the vaddr of a section but I don't know which segment it lies in. In that case, can I simply use the base address to find that section in a running program? i.e. actual address of the section in memory = base address + vaddr of the section in ELF header?
Or, there is a possibility of this not working in some cases?



I have the vaddr of a section but I don't know which segment it lies in. In that case, can I simply use the base address to find that section in a running program?

No.

If you have an ELF binary, and that binary still have section info, you can trivially find out which segment a given section belongs to. You can also see that info in readelf -Wl elf output.
(If your binary doesn't have section info, then you wouldn't know the "vaddr of a section", so I assume you do still have sections.)
The LOAD segments are often loaded with large gaps between them, so adding base load address to section address will yield wrong location in memory for any section that is not contained in the first LOAD segment.

See also this answer.
